# CQ5 Remove Render-Blocking JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, css, adobe, aem

I'm working on this document to remove blocking js:

[Remove Blocking JS](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS)

However with CQ5 we include js via:

```
<cq:includeClientLib js="headlibs"/>
```

How can I modify script tag like:

```
<script async src="my.js">
```

So I can remove blocking JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [cq:includeClientLib](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/howto/taglib.html#%3Ccq:includeClientLib%3E) does not have any options to do this. You can try using the [com.day.cq.widget.HtmlLibraryManager](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/widget/HtmlLibraryManager.html) interface to get the path of JS file, the tag is a is a convenience wrapper of this interface.

```
com.day.cq.widget.HtmlLibraryManager clientlibmanager = sling.getService(com.day.cq.widget.HtmlLibraryManager.class);
if(clientlibmanager != null)
{ 
    String[] categoryArray = {"headlibs"};
    java.util.Collection<com.day.cq.widget.ClientLibrary> libs = clientlibmanager.getLibraries(catArray,com.day.cq.widget.LibraryType.JS,false,false);
    for(com.day.cq.widget.ClientLibrary lib : libs) {
        out.write("<script async type=\"text/javascript\" src=\""+lib.getIncludePath(com.day.cq.widget.LibraryType.JS)+"\"></script>");
    }

} else {
         out.write("clientlib manager is null");
  }
```

The method `getIncludePath()` also takes an additional parameter **minified** (boolean) to give path to the minified file.

Comment: If apply this way we no more use <cq:includeClientLib js="headlibs"/> right ?

Comment: yes, the above code does what ever the cq:includeClientLib tag was doing. You can use this to create a custom Tag , so that the code is not repeated every where you want to include clientlibs. The above code is for JS only!.