# Adobe AEM: How to add "defer" attribute to script tag for scripts included through cq include clientlib tag

Tags: aem

I'm including my libraries through the `<cq:includeClientLib ../>` tag.

I wanted to include the defer value under the script tag as:

```
<script defer scr="something.js"></script>
```

But once the code is included using the include client lib tag:

```
<cq:includeClientLib categories="something.lib"/>
```

And I see that the libraries are being included as normal css and js includes:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" src="something.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="something.js"></script>
```

How  do I get the defer attribute added to the js script include as shown in the initial code above? I have tried searching on various forums and unable to find any answers.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no default configuration in AEM to add the defer tag by default. May be you can try creating a custom taglib that might help you with this.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27184337/cq5-remove-render-blocking-javascript/27187407

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this it to create a custom RequestRewriter.  This essentially allows you to change what is written to the output HTML for the client lib script tag.

This commons package has a code example where a request rewriter is used, and you could do something similar to rewrite the attributes for the script tag:

- http://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/static-reference-rewriter.html

Also see the following:

- http://www.cqblueprints.com/tipsandtricks/serving-static-assets-alt-url.html - this references a package that has an example
- https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/output-rewriting-pipelines-org-apache-sling-rewriter.html
- http://www.wemblog.com/2011/08/how-to-remove-html-extension-from-url.html
- [What am I missing for this CQ5/AEM URL rewriting scenario?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22707466/what-am-i-missing-for-this-cq5-aem-url-rewriting-scenario)
- https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/ref/javadoc/com/day/cq/rewriter/pipeline/RequestRewriter.html
- https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/rewriter/pipeline/package-summary.html